# How can I put my photos from my computer onto my blog?

Tags: blogger, photos

Until about week ago, I could upload my photographs from my computer into my blog.  Now when I click on the photo icon on the write-a-blog page, I get the box, but it doesn't have the "browse" box so I can get the photo from my files.  How can I do this?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Have you tried the tips in [this troubleshooting page](http://support.google.com/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=42538)?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using IE and Blogger? There is a [known problem](http://knownissues.blogspot.com/2013/01/the-photo-upload-icon-is-not-appearing.html) with the photo-loader at the moment.

They say:

> In the meantime, you can workaround this issue by using a different browser (such as Chrome or Firefox) or temporarily switching to the Edit HTML mode of the compose editor.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround suggestion, MaryC from NZ (or Jeroen).  That seems to work.